# changing theme through button input in Flutter

Tags: flutter

I made a button, and when that button is pressed, I want to change the color of the theme.
I am trying to modify the color with the value received from the button, but it does not work.

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    String themeColors=context.watch<DisplayList>().themeColor;
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(
        primaryColor: Colors.${themeColors}, //How do I fix this part?
      ),
```

Or is there another way to change the color?

themeColors variable already contains a string of the color to be changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't actually have a syntax like this one on Flutter: `Colors.${themeColors}`

To handle multiples themes, you need to create multiples `ThemeData` and switch them with a `ValueNotifier`.

I suggest you to use an already made community package like [theme_provider](https://pub.dev/packages/theme_provider) which will help you to switch between themes very easily.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to convert your widget to `Stateful` and use the `setState` method

```
class XYZ extends StatefulWidget {
  const XYZ({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _XYZState createState() => _XYZState();
}

class _XYZState extends State<XYZ> {
  var myAppBarThemeColor = Colors.red;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print(myAppBarThemeColor);
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData(appBarTheme: AppBarTheme(backgroundColor: myAppBarThemeColor)),
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Hello'),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: TextButton(
            onPressed: () => setState(() => myAppBarThemeColor = Colors.green),
            child: Text('Change AppBar Color'),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `findAncestorStateOfType` to manage the state of the root widget.

```dart
class App extends StatefulWidget {
  const App({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  static _AppState? of(BuildContext context) => context.findAncestorStateOfType<_AppState>();

  @override
  _AppState createState() => _AppState();
}

class _AppState extends State<App> {
  late bool isDarkMode;
  late ThemeModeStorage storage;

  void toggleDarkMode() {
    setState(() {
      isDarkMode = !isDarkMode;    
    });
    storage.writeBool(value: isDarkMode);
  }

  ...

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeConfig(isDarkMode).themeData,
      home: HomeScreen(),
    );
  }
}
```

So you can call this everywhere in your app.

```dart
App.of(context)?.toggleDarkMode();
```